# Is there any way that I can distinct with XMLAGG function

Tags: sql, xml, plsql, oracle11g

Is there any way that I can distinct with XMLAGG function.

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,A.COLUMN1 ,';').EXTRACT('//text()') 
                        ORDER BY A.COLUMN3 ).GETCLOBVAL(),';'),4000,1)
                        FROM (SELECT COLUMN1 ,COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM 
                        TABLE1) A,
                        TABLE2
                    WHERE A.COLUMN2=B.COLUMN2;
```

This is the value of that table 1. So I'd like to distinct column1 and column2 without affecting the order of column3

```
Column1      Column2    Column3
test         apple        1
test         apple        2
test         apple        3
sample       apple        4
```

The output should look like

```
column
test
sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `order` and `group` before `XMLAGG` by subquery, Try it

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,C.COLUMN1,';').EXTRACT('//text()')
     ).GETCLOBVAL(),';'),4000,1)
From ( Select A.Column1
       FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B
       WHERE A.COLUMN2=B.COLUMN2
       group by A.Column1, A.Column2
     ) C;
```